# How long has swipe left/right been a feature?

Tags: support, navigation, touch-screen

I use a Mac touchpad and only by accident discovered that a two-fingered swipe left or right navigates between topics.

How long has this been a feature and what exactly does it do in terms of deciding which topic to swipe *to*?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a feature ... *of your browser*. It's essentially navigating back and forth in your browser history. So which topics are shown is determined by which ones you just visited.

Comment: Huh, so it is :) I thought it was some rich HTML5 stuff!